# daydream app crashes on quick head rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, daydream

My daydream app is working fine when used slowly. But when I rotate my head too quick it starts giving glitches first and then the app gets crashed. I am guessing it has to do something with frames/sec loaded during high quality objects rendering or something similar. If someone has a solution, please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no errors in logcat, visual glitches are generally indicative of extremely high per frame GPU load.

It would be good to profile your app and share the crash report - but the only way I've ever been able to actually crash an app this way is with very large textures.

- Check the size and number of textures in your scene - it's possible rapid head rotation could be causing a large number of textures to need to be loaded as objects become visible.  You can also see a good list of how large the assets are at build time in Unity by inspecting the editor log after a build.  This can help make sure you aren't running out of RAM on device.
- Make sure you have texture compression and mipmaps enabled on all textures.  Disabling mip-maps on minified textures can easily overload the GPU.
- Make sure you don't have too much transparency.  Adding a lot of overdraw to the scene can overload the GPU.
- Follow performance optimization guidelines https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OptimizingGraphicsPerformance.html
  https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/virtual-reality/optimisation-vr-unity
- Make sure renderViewportScale is around 0.7, MSAA is at 2x or less, and you ***aren't*** using post-process effects, shadows, or any kind of deferred rendering
- Stay below 100 draw calls, 200k vertices on screen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such an insightful set of suggestions. I am new to Daydream platform. My app has two objects, a plain, two canvases and a terrain till now. It was working fine in my previous build with Cardboard sdk. Now when I want to make the same for daydream, this issue is coming.  Although I didn't understand more than half of it, but I will try to follow up most of them.